# Reducing JIT overhead in initial startup for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, optimization, jit

Currently developing an MVC3 application and experiencing high (multi-second) startup times. Performance profiling with ANTS pegs the only significant contributor to load time as "(JIT overhead)" at 85-90% of the time spent on load. Subsequent loads of the same page are near instant and spend ~5% of their time in the JIT.

I have used NGEN on the assemblies being loaded (and made sure they are in the GAC) and used the aspnet_compiler tool to pre-compile the site itself. Neither seem to have a significant effect on the initial startup time.

What other options are there for reducing the impact the JIT has on initial loads?

Comment: Is this on the production server?

Comment: IIS uses shadow copy to allow dynamic updates to its applications. If your site has a lot of dependencies (as is normal for MVC apps) then that may have something to do with the slow initial load as well.

Comment: This is on the production server after deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ti check as follows

1. Check if debug in web.config set to false
2. Build in release mode
3. Precompiled  views